# How to destroy a DOM element after appending it to an element in the same function

Tags: jquery, lightbox

Here is the code, I'm not even sure why it works as well as it does, line 7 isn't even valid I don't think, so why is it doing what I want it to (it reduces opacity to 0 of the lightbox and removes the loginDropDown element)? The thing that really confuses me is why doesn't it function the same when I remove line 7, when line 7 isn't even valid JQuery I just typed it by accident, is this a bug and if so how do I get it to function the same with valid code?

```
function lightBox($this) {
    if (!$('#lightBox').length > 0) {
        $('<div id="lightBox"></div>').prependTo($this);
        $("#lightBox").animate({opacity: '.4'}, 500);
    } else {
        $("#lightBox").animate({opacity: '0'}, 500);
        $('<div id="lightBox"></div>').delete();
    }
}


/** login dropdown **/
$('a#loginDropdownBtn').click(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($(this).hasClass('loginActive')) {
        $('div#loginDropdown').removeClass('loginActive');
    } else {
        $('div#loginDropdown').addClass('loginActive');
        lightBox($this);
    }
    return false;
});

/** login removal **/
$(document).click(function (event) {
    if ($(event.target).parents().index($('#loginDropdown')) == -1) {
        if ($('#loginDropdown').is(":visible")) {
            $('div#loginDropdown').removeClass('loginActive');
        }
    }
})
```

edit:
If I use-

```
        $('div#loginDropdown').removeClass('loginActive');
        $("#lightBox").animate({opacity: '0'}, 500, function() {
            $(this).remove();            
        });
```

Works! However -

```
        $("#lightBox").animate({opacity: '0'}, 500, function() {
            $(this).remove();            
        });
        $('<div id="lightBox"></div>').delete();
```

Works fine...why? Is this valid code, I can't find anything that indicates it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a callback function. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#clickMe").click(function () {
        $("#lightBox").animate({opacity: '0'}, 500, function(){$(this).remove()});
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vpbKe/

**EDIT**

Altered code to remove the login dropdown as well:

```
$("#lightBox").animate({opacity: '0'}, 500, function(){
    $(this).remove();
    $('div#loginDropdown').removeClass('loginActive');
});
```

Comment: Thanks I figured that out and was just about to edit my post, but it still doesn't remove the login element just the lightBox element (however it does animate nicely now).

Comment: @Ian Edited my answer. Is that what you need? If not, can you please add more detail in the question?

Comment: That definitely works but I'd still really like to understand why my new code works also. BTW thanks, I totally had a face-palm moment with this one.

Comment: @Ian I'm not sure why that code works for you. "delete" is not a valid jQuery method. Can you check the console? It's possible that that line is throwing an exception that's causing some unexpected behavior that just happens to "work" for what you're looking at.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify why it works with line #7(I better say *"what happens with line 7"*)

at the end of `$('a#loginDropdownBtn').click()` is a `return false` . When this function returns `false`, it will prevent the `click`-event from firing for the document.

But this function will not return `false`, because the error that happens in `lightBox()` will stop the further execution of `$('a#loginDropdownBtn').click()` .

How to get the same behaviour without the faulty line #7? Remove the `return false` at the end of `$('a#loginDropdownBtn').click()` .

Comment: Ah, great explanation thanks - unfortunately for some reason e.preventDefault(); isn't working (yes I'm passing e to the function handler). I've read something about a clear or empty in previous code somehow breaking e.preventDefault(); but I couldn't figure out what they meant. Either way I got it to work with the return false.